# How to avoid ruining TinyMCE popups with url rewriting?

Tags: url-rewriting, tinymce

I have a website which uses TinyMCE textboxes for editing. It works fine except for the toolbar options which open a popup window as it seems to be caught by my url rewriting in the .htaccess file. Each of them show my 404-page. The url rewriting is set up so that all urls (except ajax calls) are sent to an index.php file. It seems obvious that the popup windows are caught by this as well but I have no idea what url signatrues to look for in the .htaccess file, so do anyone know what kind of pattern I can match against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @[andyk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483881/how-to-avoid-ruining-tinymce-popups-with-url-rewriting#483899) pointed out, you can use a .htaccess in your TinyMCE folder to override the global settings that are doing the URL rewriting. I've done this in the past myself to resolve the same issue.

If that's not attractive to you for whatever reason, the other option is to exclude the tinyMCE folder like so:

```
# if URL starts with /TinyMCE, stop processing here
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/TinyMCE [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

This sets a rewrite condition to check for the directory TinyMCE is in, and if found, the rule .* - means for all URLS, do nothing and the [L] means stop processing here.

Answer (score 1):

try putting an exception in your htaccess for the tinyMCE folder maybe ?

Comment: +1 - I had this exact same problem with one of my sites and fixed it by putting a .htaccess in the TinyMCE folder to override it.